# Python Version Numbering Scheme

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

The Python website provides several different versions within the download section.

I understand the distinction between Python 2.x and 3.x, but I am confused about the different versions of Python 3.x.

For example, their website currently lists the three most recent releases as:

- **Python 3.4.6** (2017-01-17)
- **Python 3.5.3** (2017-01-17)
- **Python 3.6.0** (2016-12-23)

Clearly, the most recent release is 3.4.6, but it is not the largest release number.

What is the distinction between these three different versions?  Should I install the most recent version, or the largest release number?

Comment: Check this http://semver.org/

Comment: If you want to use the most recently updated version, you will constantly be switching versions. If you target the highest version number, you'll only switch versions every time there's a new release. Also, given enough time, a higher version number will always have a more recent update than a lower version number.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this](http://semver.org/), a version number is defined by

MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH

where

1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes
2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
3. PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

According to [this](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.4.0/) and [this](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/) Python 3.5.0 was released in 2015-09-13, while Python 3.4.0 was released on March 16th, 2014.

The third number in the version number is the PATCH which usually fixes bugs, so the last version of Python is 3.6.0 which has no patches so far. I recommend to use the version based on the compatibility of the libraries you are going to use.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is a wonderful answer.  As a secondary question, do most packages explicitly state which version number they work with?  Also, if a package says something like "works with 3.4+" does that generally mean it will work with version 3.6, or would it only work with 3.4.x?

Comment: @user3317176: If it says "3.4+", that includes 3.6.

Comment: @user3317176, it depends on the library. For example, in this page [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/faq/install/) it says which version of that package is compatible with which version of Python, and as user2357112 says, if you have something as version 3.4+ means that it will be compatible with version >= 3.4.0.

Comment: Another question.  Does Python 3.6 not have all the features of 3.4?  It seems strange to support both 3.4 and 3.5 and 3.6 at the same time.

Comment: @ncuccia, you can see what is new in Python 3.6 [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html)

Comment: Where does it say that Python uses semantic versioning?

Comment: To answer my own comment, this PEP does seem to say that Python somewhat adheres to semantic versioning: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#id50

Comment: Python doesn’t use semver.

Comment: @PunchyRascal that PEP appears to be about teaching developers how to version their packages, not about the versioning used by Python itself.

Comment: I have downvoted your answer. Reason: Python [does not use SemVer](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/general.html#how-does-the-python-version-numbering-scheme-work). As such, your answer adds nothing worthwhile to the discussion. At worse, you are inadvertently spreading misinformation by stating that Python follows SemVer.

Answer (score 9):

Contrary to popular belief, Python (the language) **does not** use SemVer. Quoting [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/general.html#how-does-the-python-version-numbering-scheme-work):

> Python versions are numbered “A.B.C” or “A.B”:
>
> - A is the major version number – it is only incremented for really major changes in the language.
> - B is the minor version number – it is incremented for less earth-shattering changes.
> - C is the micro version number – it is incremented for each bugfix release.

Every so-called "minor version" of Python includes breaking changes, unlike SemVer. These backwards-incompatible changes are usually documented in the "Porting to Python X.Y" section of the "What’s New" page for each version (eg. [the one for 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#porting-to-python-3-11)).

Major version updates are only reserved for large-scale breaking changes. The last major version update was Python 3, which deliberately brought many backwards-incompatible changes to the language (such as a rework of string types and changing print to a function), resulting in a transition period that lasted nearly 15 years.

Comment: Question owner should accept this as the answer.