# What does Python major version incompatible API changes mean?

Tags: python

After reading this quesiton: [Python Version Numbering Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259098/python-version-numbering-scheme), I wonder what does "MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes" mean for Python?

My guess:

1. CPython incompatible API(function signature) changes ?
2. The Python language syntax changes ?
3. CPython incompatible API changes which also leads to the language syntax change ?

Which assumption above is correct?

An example would be much appreciated.

For example, from Python2 to Python3, `print 'a'` changes to `print('a')`. This is an incompatible language syntax change. Does it has some incompatiable underlying CPython API change? I don't know.

Comment: I think it refers to #2, because the others are implementation-specific, not the general python version number.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, or what you mean by "internal C API".  As a rule, Python add-on modules in C and C++ must be recompiled when the minor version number changes.  There are no guarantees at all about the internal structure of the interpreter itself.

Comment: The answer you quote is referring to the semantic versioning convention which is widely used by many software projects, not just Python. I suggest you click the link that author gives to read more about semver.

Comment: @Barmar And also semantics and builtins, not just syntax. The change of semantics of `str` between 2.7 and 3.x comes to mind.

Comment: @TimRoberts I want to say C API changes, for example, `int foo(int b)` now changes to `int foo(double b)`, and thus "incompatiable"

Comment: @Barmar Ok I seem to get the idea. So "incompatiable changes" means the language itself, whether the underying implementation woud have need or made incompatiable changes is not directly related to the Python version number.

Comment: Right. In this cas, "API" means the public programming interface, which means language syntax and interfaces to the standard library functions. Another example is the incompatible differences in the `input()` function between Python 2 and 3 (Python 3 input is like Python 2 raw_input)

Answer (score 1):

For your particular example, in Python 2 print is a statement and in Python3 it is a function. So you would be right in the way that the API would change to accommodate it as a function